# Why is a program not finding a library that's right in the same directory as the program?

Tags: python

I'm trying to get a program from GitHub up and running.  When I run the `setup.py` program it comes with, I get the following error message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmpfit
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-g++' failed with exit status 1
```

This is happening even though I put the `mpfit` directory right in the same directory as `setup.py`.
I'm using Ubuntu on Windows 10, with Python 2.7.

Does anyone know what I might be missing?  Thank you!

Comment: Why not link to the GitHub project in question? Also, you can't just drop a directory next to `setup.py` and expect it to find a native dynamic library. Dynamic linking works a bit differently from Python imports. What distro are you running? Can you e.g. `sudo apt install libmpfit`?

Comment: I think I might have figured out part of the problem: I needed to download and install a different mpfit program instead.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to link to `libmpfit.so` (which is basically what `-lmpfit` means), it is generally considered best to install it in a the standard directory for shared libraries. Often this is `/usr/local/lib`.

If `libmpfit` is written in C or C++, it might need to be compiled and installed before you can use it. (Unless you've downloaded a pre-built binary.)

If Ubuntu has a package for `libmpfit`, I would suggest using that, because in that case the people who have packaged the software for Ubuntu have done the hard work for you. Such a package will install the files in the right places for you.

If you have to built `libmpfit` yourself, unpack the source package. That will usually contain a text file named README or INSTALL that will tell you how to build and install the library. Read them carefully; you might need extra libraries or tools to build `libmpfit`.

Comment: I think I might have actually needed to download and install a different mpfit program instead.  Thank you!